# House Plant With Round Waxy Leaves Identification

Tags: identification, houseplants

Can anyone help me identify what plant I have here? I got it from my parents a while ago and they can’t remember what it is either. Help me please. Thanks in advance. [image]

Answer (score 3):

Looks like Peperomia obtusifolia - it seems to be variegated, and is not getting enough light for the variegation to show up properly on all the leaves. It doesn't like full sunlight much, but bright daylight is good, so something like a north facing windowsill, if possible. https://www.canarius.com/en/plants/peperomia-obtusifolia-cv-usa.html

Comment: Thank you for your response. I live in an apartment with only a couple windows so finding spots for my plants is hard. But I will get a new rack or something for it. ☺️

Comment: Well, it looks pretty healthy anyway - if you're not unhappy with its lower level of variegation, don't worry about it. One side is getting more light than the other, maybe just turn it occasionally?